# "App has stopped" message occur whenever I am trying to build my react-native app on my mobile device

Tags: build.gradle, react-native

Whenever I am trying to run my application on my mobile it shows "App has stopped" however the cmd terminal shows "build successful" message I already have tried all the solutions similar to my problem but all those solutions failed in my case can anyone suggest me the right solution to my problem I am attaching the screenshot of my build. [you can check the build here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUjFJ.png)

Comment: Look at the logs in Logcat from your device to find out why it's crashing. Could be a missing bundle or some library crashing your app on boot.

Comment: I am new to react-native can you guide me where can I see Logcat?

Comment: Do you have Android Studio installed?

Comment: Yes I have Android Studio installed.  I am using windows 10

Comment: Open your project in Android Studio, oh the bottom you’ll see _Logs_, in there you can see what’s causing the crash. This link will help https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat

Comment: Thanks @alizahid for your help I created a new project and its working fine.